# ZSH history completion menu

Tags: shell, autocomplete, zsh

Zsh autocomplete is amazing, but I cannot configure one thing properly: 
I want zsh to offer me a list of commands from history.

I know that I can search the history with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, but I want something a bit different. When I type:

> shelajev@elephant ~ » kill 1<kbd>TAB</kbd>
>    1642 shelajev gnome-keyring-d
>    1718 shelajev gnome-session
>    1807 shelajev ssh-agent
>    1810 shelajev dbus-launch
>    1811 shelajev dbus-daemon
>    1822 shelajev gnome-settings-
>    1884 shelajev gvfsd
>    1891 shelajev gvfs-fuse-daemo

Zsh offers me a list of processes to kill. I want to have something like this:

> shelajev@elephant ~ » kill <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
>    kill -9 12093
>    kill -15 4123

where those items in the list are taken from my history.

There exists a ZLE hist-complete thing, but I don't know how to properly configure it.

I have the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
zle -C hist-complete complete-word _generic
zstyle ':completion:hist-complete:*' completer _history
bindkey "^X^X" hist-complete
```

But this only completes individual words, which doesn't give me much. Is there a way to combine history search for **lines** in the history and showing a listing of that?

Answer (score 19):

there is something in zsh called `history-beginning-search-menu`.
if you put:

```
autoload -Uz history-beginning-search-menu
zle -N history-beginning-search-menu
bindkey '^X^X' history-beginning-search-menu
```

in your .zshrc file. then for example:

```
kent$  sudo systemctl[here I type C-X twice]
Enter digits:
01 sudo systemctl acpid.service                      11 sudo systemctl enable netfs
02 sudo systemctl enable acpid                       12 sudo systemctl enable networkmanager
03 sudo systemctl enable alsa                        13 sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager
04 sudo systemctl enable alsa-restore                14 sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online
05 sudo systemctl enable alsa-store                  15 sudo systemctl enable ntpd
06 sudo systemctl enable cronie                      16 sudo systemctl enable sshd
07 sudo systemctl enable cups                        17 sudo systemctl enable syslog-ng
08 sudo systemctl enable dbus                        18 sudo systemctl enable tpfand
09 sudo systemctl enable gdm                         19 sudo systemctl reload gdm.service
10 sudo systemctl enable hal                         20 sudo systemctl restart gdm.service
```

then you need to give the index number to fire the command in history.

of course there could be some optimization for that. but I think this gets you start.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly as you said. It's a great starting point!
I just wonder if there's a way to enhance this with something like *menu select*.

Comment: I am also looking for potential menu select + digit select combination. @OlegŠelajev did you find any?

Comment: Haven't found anything, but I didn't look into it much.

Comment: Oleg @MikkoOhtamaa See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65461206/13832769). 

Answer (score 8):

My [Zsh Autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) includes a proper history menu, plus [real-time multi-line history search](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete#live-history-search). Try it out and let me know what you think!

[image: live history search]

[image: history menu with multi-select]

Comment: @marlon-richert I tried to follow manual steps (https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete#manual-installation) but it is not working. I open my iterm terminal but not getting any suggestion.

Comment: @Badman This is not the right place to discuss that. Feel free to open an issue at my GitHub repo, though: https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete/issues

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the top match auto-completed in the current line (like fish shell), try [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions). When you type a command similar to a command in history, it suggests a completion with light-grey text. You can press → to accept the completion.

[image: zsh-autosuggestions]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years have passed and now there's a plugin called [zsh-navigation-tools](https://github.com/psprint/zsh-navigation-tools). It doesn't exactly do what you were looking for, but maybe you or someone else might find it helpful. However, it should be noted that it replaces the default bck-i-search (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) by a fullscreen application.

Credits to [Mike](https://superuser.com/a/1051789/275251) for pointing me to this plugin.